# Issue with aspxcheckbox checkedchanged event handler not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I am having an issue with using the checkedchanged event handler.
The following is my scenario:

I have an aspxcheckbox that is inside of a DataItemTemplate
 that is inside of a gridviewdatacheckcolumn 
 that is inside of an aspxgridview.

Here is my aspx code:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gvCustomerCertificates" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Caption="Customer Certificates" Width="100%">
                                <Columns>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CertNo" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" 
                                        VisibleIndex="1" ReadOnly="True">
                                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CustManufacturer" Caption="Manufacturer" ShowInCustomizationForm="True"
                                        VisibleIndex="2" ReadOnly="True">
                                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CustDesc" Caption="Description" 
                                        ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="3" ReadOnly="True">
                                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CustModel" Caption="Model" 
                                        ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="4" ReadOnly="True">
                                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CustSerialNo" Caption="Serial No" ShowInCustomizationForm="True"
                                        VisibleIndex="5" ReadOnly="True">
                                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CustControlNo" Caption="Control No" ShowInCustomizationForm="True"
                                        VisibleIndex="6" ReadOnly="True">
                                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn FieldName="CalDate" ShowInCustomizationForm="True"
                                        VisibleIndex="7" ReadOnly="True">
                                        <PropertiesDateEdit DisplayFormatString="MM/dd/yyyy">
                                        </PropertiesDateEdit>
                                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" />
                                    </dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CustAssetNo" Caption="Asset No" ShowInCustomizationForm="True"
                                        VisibleIndex="8" ReadOnly="True">
                                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>


                                     <dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn FieldName="Verified" Caption="Verified" ShowInCustomizationForm="True"
                                        VisibleIndex="9" >

                                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
                                        <DataItemTemplate>
                                            <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="check_Changed" ClientInstanceName="chk" Enabled="True" >
                                            </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
                                         </DataItemTemplate>       


                                    </dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn>


                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="VerifiedInitials" Caption="Initials" ShowInCustomizationForm="True"
                                        VisibleIndex="10">
                                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn FieldName="PDFName" Caption="PDF" ShowInCustomizationForm="True"
                                        VisibleIndex="11" ReadOnly="True">
                                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
                                        <PropertiesHyperLinkEdit Target="_blank" Text="View">
                                            <Style ForeColor="#1FB259"></Style>
                                        </PropertiesHyperLinkEdit>
                                    </dx:GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn>
                                </Columns>
                                <Settings ShowFilterBar="Visible" ShowFilterRow="True" ShowHeaderFilterButton="True" />
                                <SettingsText EmptyDataRow="Currently no Certificates available for your account." />


                            </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

I am trying to get the checkedChanged event to call a method "Check_Changed" in the code behind but the event handler is never fired.

Here is my check_Changed method in the code behind:

```
Protected Sub check_Changed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    'test to see if event handler is firing
    MsgBox("Hey")

    Dim cb As ASPxCheckBox = TryCast(sender, ASPxCheckBox)

    Dim container As GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer = TryCast(cb.NamingContainer, GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer)
    cb.ClientInstanceName = String.Format("cbCheck{0}", container.VisibleIndex)
    cb.Checked = gvCustomerCertificates.Selection.IsRowSelected(container.VisibleIndex)


    ' creates a sql connection and opens it
    Dim scSQLConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection() With {.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item("Main").ConnectionString}
    scSQLConnection.Open()

    ' create a data table
    Try

        Dim sqlCommand As New SqlCommand() With {.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblVerified VALUES (" + gvCustomerCertificates.Columns.Item("CertNo").ToString}

        Dim daCommand As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand)
        daCommand.SelectCommand.Connection = scSQLConnection
        sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally

    End Try

    scSQLConnection.Close()

End Sub
```

Currently all I am trying to do is get the msgbox to appear so that I know the event is being triggered, my eventual goal is to insert a record into the database when the checkbox is clicked, I am inserting a record into a different table than the ones bound to the gridview so I have to use an insert statement as opposed to binding the field to the table.

Please let me know if you can help or if I need to clarify anything.
Thank You!

Comment: I'm not sure VB message box is proper way to check if method is called in ASP.NET environment. Have you tried with breakpoint in check_Changed method?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a dropdownlist not firing the selectedItemChanged event. For me nothing helped till I found out, the IE11 has problems with some events. Maybe that's a short answer to your question.

Comment: I am testing this application using Google Chrome, I also have a breakpoint in the method but I am using the msgbox as well, the control does a postback when clicked but it never hits the check_changed method, thank you for taking a look at my issue anything you can tell me is helpful.